# Fatal error: Call to a member function getCollection() MAGENTO

Tags: function, magento, fatal-error

Fatal error: Call to a member function getCollection() on a non-object in /home/mysite/public_html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php line 618

```
 /** @var $websiteCollection Mage_Core_Model_Store */
---> $storeCollection = Mage::getModel('core/store')->getCollection()
        ->initCache($this->getCache(), 'app', array(Mage_Core_Model_Store::CACHE_TAG))
        ->setLoadDefault(true);
```

Hi there

Is someone encounter this error on magento 1.7.0.2? We have 2 store
Store 1 default
Store 2 is a symbolic link from Store 1 it's because of ssl certificate

Before the site was working fine but last week we encounter this error when we install an extension and uninstalled it, its because its not working.

Comment: Did you clear cache and delete sessions after you uninstalled the extension?  Which extension was it?

Comment: Yes Zak they clear and delete the cache and session after uninstalled its ET_Currency Manager, but I submit a ticket to them they said Currency Manager does not use any kind of collections and the issue is not related to their extension.

Comment: Can you please share extension details(functionality) ?

Comment: For more details here's the link of extension
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/et-currency-manager.html but Currency Manager does not use any kind of collections and the issue is not related to their extension - from the developer.

Comment: I installed, then uninstalled/cleared cache and everything is fine.  My guess is you missed an XML file somewhere, but I can't be sure.  this is why we back up our installation prior to any extension install!

Comment: thanks Zak for your information

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was causing this error?